# Text And Formula In Shape Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to add a formula and text to a shape that builds out as a demonstration for a product.

Currently I'm using a dataset which I reference for the value.

I however cannot get text to show. So for example the calculation is equal to 7. I need to be able to add days. to the end. So the final result is 7 Days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research it seems that a shape only allows for a cell reference, not a formula or function.

If you would like to use a formula inside a shape, you will need to put the formula inside another cell and reference that inside the shape

Answer (score 1):

Try `=A1+A2&" Days"` or `=CONCATENATE(A1+A2," Days")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply zx8754, I however found out that you cannot write a formula inside of a shape. I managed to bypass this using a config sheet which I just reference by the cell.